# Multidimensional integration over unit sphere and Steiner's point calculation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry

**Hello everyone!**

This is my first post here, so please be patient with me. 
I am sorry for my English, hope you will understand me.

I want to compute position of the Steiner's point of half of the ball. To do that, I need to evaluate integral which goes over unit sphere.

**For 2 dimensional case:**

I have found out, that integral of function $f(x,y)$ over some curve can be computed like this:

$$ \int\limits_S f(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}S = \int\limits_D f\left(\textbf{r}(t)\right) \Vert \textbf{r}^{'}(t) \Vert_2 \ \mathrm{d}t,$$
where the first integral goes over the curve (in my case unit sphere), while the second one is standard integral. $\textbf{r}(t)$ is parametrization of the curve (sphere) and $\textbf{r}^{'}(t)$ is vector of derivatives.

Unit sphere is:

$$ S = \{ (x,y)\  \vert \  x^2 + y^2 = 1  \}$$

Assume function $h$: $h(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

If I split the integration over this unit sphere $S$ into two parts - for upper half ($I$, $y \geq 0$) and lower half ($II$, $y < 0$) of the sphere, I can use this parametrization:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \textbf{r}_{I}(t) & = & \displaystyle t \cdot \textbf{i} & + & h(t) \cdot \textbf{j} \\
 \textbf{r}_{II}(t) & = &\displaystyle t \cdot \textbf{i} & - & h(t) \cdot \textbf{j}
\end{array}
$$

where $t$ is single parameter (going between $-1$ and $1$) and $\textbf{i}, \textbf{j}$ are standard unit vectors.

$\Vert \textbf{r}^{'}(t) \Vert_2$ would be equal to $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right)^2}$

With this I should be able to compute the position of Steiner's point.

The formula is:
$$ s(A) = \frac{1}{V(B^n)} \cdot \int_{S^{n-1}} e \cdot h_A(e)\ \mathrm{d}\lambda(e),$$

where $V(B^n)$ is volume of n-ball, the integral goes over unit sphere so $e$ is unit vector on that sphere and $h_A(e)$ is value of the support function in the direction of $e$.

Support function is defined as:

$$ h_A(\textbf{x}) = \max\{ \left\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{p} \right\rangle \vert\ \textbf{p} \in A \},$$

where $A$ is the half of ball.
$$ A = \{ (x,y)\  \vert \  x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2,\  y \geq 0  \},$$
where $r$ is some fixed radius.

Values of the support function $h_A(\textbf{e})$ for $\textbf{e} = (x,y)$ would be:

$r$ (radius of $A$) for $y \geq 0$, which is true in area $I$

$r \vert x \vert$ for $y < 0$, which is true in area $II$

I decided to compute Steiner's point coordinates one after another. So now I have 4 standard integrals (2 for $x$ position and $y$ position) $\times$ (2 for area $I$ and area $II$):

$V(B^2) = \pi \cdot R^2$, $R = 1$ for our unit ball

**For the upper half ($I$):**

$h_A(\textbf{e}) = r$, unit vector $\textbf{e} = (t, \sqrt{1-t^2})$ 
$$ s(A)_{I_x} =  \frac{1}{V(B^2)} \cdot \int_{-1}^{1}  t \cdot r \cdot \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right)^2  + 1} \ \mathrm{d}t =  0
$$

$$ s(A)_{I_y} =  \frac{1}{V(B^2)} \cdot \int_{-1}^{1}  \sqrt{1-t^2} \cdot r \cdot \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right)^2  + 1} \ \mathrm{d}t =  \frac{2r}{\pi}
$$

**For the lower half ($II$):**

$h_A(\textbf{e}) = r \vert x \vert$, $\textbf{e} = (t,-\sqrt{1-t^2})$
$$ s(A)_{II_x} =  \frac{1}{V(B^2)} \cdot \int_{-1}^{1}  t \cdot r\vert t \vert \cdot \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right)^2  + 1} \ \mathrm{d}t = 0
$$

$$ s(A)_{II_x} =  \frac{1}{V(B^2)} \cdot \int_{-1}^{1} - \sqrt{1-t^2} \cdot r\vert t \vert \cdot \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right)^2  + 1} \ \mathrm{d}t = -\frac{r}{\pi} 
$$

So, if I sum those results for area $I$ and $II$, I would get position of Steiner's point of $A$:
$$s(A) = \left(0,\frac{r}{\pi}\right)$$

**My first question is: Are my calculations correct or do I miss something important?**

Now, If I assume the result is correct. I wanted to continue in 3D. As I found, the integration over sphere could be computed like this:

$$ \iint\limits_S f(x,y,z) \ \mathrm{d}S = \iint\limits_D f\left(\textbf{r}(u,v)\right) \Vert \textbf{r}_u \times \textbf{r}_v \Vert \ \mathrm{d}A,$$

where $\textbf{r}$ is parametrization of the sphere and  $\textbf{r}_u$, $\textbf{r}_v$ are partial derivatives.

Assume function h: $h(u,v)= \sqrt{1-u^2 - v^2}$

I would split the integration again and integrate over upper half ($I$) and lower half ($II$). The parametrization would be like this:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \textbf{r}_{I}(u,v) & = &  u\textbf{i} + v\textbf{j} + \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\textbf{k} \\
 \textbf{r}_{II}(u,v) & = &  u\textbf{i} + v\textbf{j} - \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\textbf{k} \\
\end{array}
$$

where $u,v$ are parameters. $u$ is going from $-1$ to $1$ and  $v$ is going from $-\sqrt{1-u^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-u^2}$.

$$ \Vert \textbf{r}_{u} \times \textbf{r}_{v} \Vert =  \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}\right)^2 + 1}$$

That seems similar to 2D case.

**So, my second question (assuming that results of 2D case were correct): If I wanted to compute it again in 4D, assuming  function h would become $h(a,b,c)= \sqrt{1-a^2 - b^2 - c^2}$, could I replace $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}\right)^2 + 1}$ from 3D case by $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial c}\right)^2 + 1}$ (and with that integrate over unit sphere in 4D similarly)?**

**My last question** is about $\Vert \textbf{r}^{'}(t) \Vert_2$, $\Vert \textbf{r}_{u} \times \textbf{r}_{v} \Vert$, $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial c}\right)^2 + 1}$ respectively.

I suppose it's some kind of weight for the integration to give correct result. **Is there some geometric meaning behind that?** I am a little bit lost there.

Thank you very much for your guidance!